# Is a new universe created when dark energy rips open a singularity?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, dark-energy

Dark energy will tear everything apart, even black holes. Is a new universe created when dark energy rips open the singularity of a black hole ? And does the topology of the universe depend on the type of singularity ?

Comment: Dark energy will only tear everything apart if it increases in strength. There is absolutely zero experimental evidence that it is doing that—all the experimental evidence is that its strength has been constant over the history of the universe. The dark-energy-ripping-everything-apart scenarios are currently the unfounded speculations of theoretical physicists.

Comment: Do you mean an alternate universe or destroying our univirse and replacing it?

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to think that it would.  All black holes will eventually [Hawking-radiate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation) away.  There's no evidence that the repulsion of dark energy is actually increasing (as Peter Shor notes), so the ultimate fate of the universe will most likely be a heat death, which will happen long after all black holes have radiated away.